# Draw a shadow color around a shape?

Tags: qt4

Is it possoble to draw a pencolor transparent.

I make a shape through paint now the problem is that i want to outline that shape with a transparent color .The purpose will also solve by shadowing its boundry. How it can implement .
Please tell me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A QPen can be created from a QColor, which can have alpha values. An alpha value is what's going to give you the transparency effect.

When drawing an item, the pen is the outline color and the brush is the fill color. So in your case you want to set the pen before you start drawing. (Note: you may have to give it a width).

```
painter->setPen(QPen( QColor(qRgba(0, 10, 20, 50))));
// Draw your item
```